# If statement not working correctly

Tags: java, android, if-statement, arraylist

I'm making an App for Android that would allow you to see if a date is available. If the date isn't in the arraylist it will get added in, if the date is in the arraylist then the user will receive a message "please try again".

The If statement wont work and never gives the "please try again" message regardless if the date entered is already in the arraylist. I have confirmed that the data is being written into the arraylist.

```
@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.second_activity); 

            final ArrayList<String> DateArray = new ArrayList<String>(); 
            DateArray.add("0101"); //test code

            addListenerRadioGroup(); //not important

            mNextButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.NextButton); 
            mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mEditText2 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                    if (DateArray.contains(mEditText2)) { //looks for edit text info
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), //This should pop up if user
                                "please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //enters "0101"
                    } else {


                    DateArray.add(mEditText2.getText().toString()); }

                }

            });




     }
```

Comment: An ArrayList<String> will never contain an EditText object. You need convert mEditText2 to a string equivalent and then use contains.

Comment: @JGrice `mEditText2` already will be converted with the implicit `toString()` call and that's why this `if` statement doesn't work. It is necessary to extract the desired information of this EditText by calling `mEditText2.getText()`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your if statement conditional is testing if the EditText object is in the ArrayList.  You probably want to test for the String value of the EditText object because your ArrayList stores Strings.

Comment: Even though this chance is really easy, it would made you answer complete if you provide necessary code.

Comment: Note the OP knew enough to call toString on the insert but forgot that step on the test.  She was very close.

Comment: mEditText2.getText().toString()

Answer (score 0):

```
you are checking if condition with providing wrong condition. 


  if (DateArray.contains(mEditText2));
```

Here mEditText2 should be any String.you are passing edittext reference.

Answer (score 0):

From your EditText you can put into ArrayList the String value

```
final ArrayList<String> DateArray = new ArrayList<String>(); 
            DateArray.add("0101");
```

`DateArray.add(mEditText2.getText().toString())`

But when you look for edit text info you are chacking edittext object not string value.

Try this way..

```
if(DateArray.contains(mEditText2.getText().toString())
```